# continuous map on $\mathbb{R}$ which is the identity on $\mathbb{Q}$ is the identity map, hence Aut$(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q})= 1.$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Prove that any continuous map on $\mathbb{R}$ which is the identity on $\mathbb{Q}$ is the identity map, hence Aut$(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q})= 1.$

proof: Suppose $\sigma$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ which is an identity on $\mathbb{Q}$. let $a \in R $. Then since $\sigma$ is continuous, then by definition there is $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $|a - b| < \delta_1$.

And assume $|\sigma(a) -\sigma(b)| < \epsilon/2$ .

Let $\delta $= min{$\epsilon/2, \delta_1$}.

And now let $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|a - b| < \epsilon$. Then

$|\sigma(a) - a| = |\sigma(a)  - b + b - a| \leq |\sigma(a) - \sigma(b) | + |b - a| < \epsilon/2 + |b-a|$.

Can someone please help me? I am not sure . Can I say $|b - a| < \epsilon/2 $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with $\epsilon-\delta$ here is how it can be done:

Let $a \in \mathbb R$.

Let $\epsilon >0$. As you said, by continuity there is a $\delta$ such that for all $|x-a| < \delta$ you have $|\sigma(x)-\sigma(a)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Now pick some $b \in \mathbb Q$ such that
$$
|b-a| < min\{ \frac{\epsilon}{2}, \delta  \} 
$$

Then, as $\sigma(b)=b$ you have
$$
|\sigma(a)-a|\leq |\sigma(a)-b|+|b-a| = |\sigma(a)-\sigma(b)|+|b-a| <\frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$

This shows that 
$$
|\sigma(a)-a| < \epsilon$$
for all $\epsilon >0$.

This looks like what you were trying to do, you solution is pretty close, but not very clean.

Comment: the $x$ at the beginning $|x - a| < \delta$ is it a real number too?

Comment: @Mahidevran The definition of continuity is that for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists some $\delta$ such that for ALL $x$  with $|x-a|< \delta$ you have .... I used $x$ and you used $b$, it is the same thing ...

Answer (score 4):

It will be much easier to do this exercise using sequences.

Hint: Note that every real number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers and that continuous functions preserve limits of sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Complement to @Nitrogen's answer:

**Hint.** Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let define: $$x_n:=\frac{\lfloor 10^nx\rfloor}{10^n}\in\mathbb{Q}.$$
One has: $$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}x_n=x.$$

Comment: where does  $10^n$ come from?

Comment: @Mahidevran It's simply the truncated decimal expansion of $x$.

Comment: If $Y$ is a Hausdorff space and $f,g$ are continuous from $X$ to $Y$ then the set $A=\{p\in X :f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed in $X.$ In particular,when $X=Y=R, $ and $A$ is dense in $R,$ we have $ f=g.$ So if $g=id_R$ and $Q\subset A$ then $f=id_R$.

Comment: @C.Falcon how does $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \left[ 10^n x \right] }{ 10^n } = x $$ hold? Can you please show this rigorously?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood For sure, recall that for all $y\in\mathbf{R}$, $\lfloor y\rfloor\leqslant x<\lfloor y\rfloor+1$, hence with $y=10^nx$ and dividing by $10^n$, it holds that:
$$x\leqslant\frac{\lfloor 10^nx\rfloor}{10^n}<x+\frac{1}{10^n},$$
whence the result using the squeeze theorem.